# UTF-8 issues when deploying as a WAR or running under Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, utf-8, internationalization, war

In my grails application, UTF-8 handling is screwed up when I run under Tomcat as a war. When I do run app, the following request string of:

`utf-8-demo-%C3%BC%C4%81%D1%84.txt` is set to `utf-8-demo-üāф.txt`, with 3 unicode escape sequences sent back for each of the unicode characters in the string for all subsequent requests.

Under tomcat, this comes back as `utf-8-demo-Ã¼ÄÑ.txt`, or `utf-8-demo-\u00C3\u00BC\u00C4\u0081\u00D1\u0084.txt`.

In one of my controllers, I have this:

```
String s = params.file
log.info( "Filename: $s" )//works in run-app, fails under tomcat
```

What could POSSIBLY be causing this behavior dichotomy between run-app and deploying as a war under tomcat?

Comment: Have you followed the steps in http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2, i.e. set `URIEncoding` and maybe `useBodyEncodingForURI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` on the `<Connector>` definition in `server.xml`.